# retrieving information from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `incidents`, that i'd like to retrieve 4 fields/columns from, but i need `firstname` and `lastname` from the `customer` table. I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

This is the relevant code:

```
public static function get_incidents_unassigned(){
    $db = Database::getDB();
    $query = 'SELECT concat(customer.firstName,customer.lastName) AS name, incident.productCode, incident.dateOpened, incident.title, incident.description FROM incidents

            INNER JOIN customers
            ON incident.customerID = customer.customerID
            WHERE techID IS NULL';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $rows = $statement->fetch();

    $incidentList = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row){    
        $incidents = new Incident(
                $row['name'], $row['productCode'],
                $row['dateOpened'], $row['title'], $row['description']);

        $incidentList[] = $incident;
    }
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $incidentList;
}
```

******but this is the involved table

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Date Opened</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($incidents as $incident) :
        $ts = strtotime($incident->getDate_Opened());
        $date_opened_formatted = date('n/j/Y', $ts);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer->getFullName()); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($incident->getProduct_Code()); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($incident->getTitle()); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($incident->getDescription()); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $date_opened_formatted; ?></td>
        <td><form action="." method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action"
                   value="select_incident">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_code"
                   value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($incident->getIncident_id()); ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Select">
        </form></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

//****may have been looking at too long!
```

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO?

Comment: 1) You have two `foreach`: the error is referred to what line? (can be either wrongs...); 2) if you use pdo, `->fetch()` return a single row, if you use mysqli, `->fetch()` doesn't return any rows; 3) in second `foreach`, you use `$incidents`: where it is defined?

Comment: Using PDO. The error points to the foreach line in the get_incidents_unassigned function. I edited the line : $incidents = new Incident in the get_incidents_unassigned function. I had $i in there from previous code.

Comment: query is golden, returns everything proper in myadmin, but not loading array properly i assume.?

Answer (score 0):

You should add some error handling to your code. The db could tell you that incident is not defined. The data is selected from incidents but incident is used to identify the fields.

I mean try changing your statement to match your circumstances

```
 $query = 'SELECT concat(customer.firstName,customer.lastName) AS name,
    inc.productCode, inc.dateOpened, inc.title,
    inc.description FROM incidents inc

    INNER JOIN customers
    ON inc.customerID = customer.customerID
    WHERE techID IS NULL';
```

Your database is able to give you error messages. These error messages describe what is your problem with your statement

Comment: should i do that first? figured i'd find the errors helpful. I'm new, do you mean print out array in function to see if loaded?